# Why "finally:" block is executed after the return statement in a "try:" block in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, return

According to my understanding：return is the meaning of returning a value.

One example, the python1 script:

```
def func():  
    try:  
       print 98  
       return 'ok' 
    finally: 
       print 98  

print fun()
```

The output of the script is :

98

98

ok

So my question is why the output of the script is not:

98

OK

98

Why is the output of the OK line at the end?

Comment: Because the `finally` block is executed before the function exits and returns.

Comment: did you read 
 [about cleanup actions when handling errors](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) ?

Comment: From docs: *A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try statement, whether an exception has occurred or not.*

Comment: [The finally clause is also executed “on the way out” when any other clause of the try statement is left via a break, continue or return statement.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions)

Comment: Please edit your question so the Title has any resemblence to what you ask in the description of your post - currently based on the tile no one will ever be able to find this

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use

```
try:
  #some code
finally:
  #some other code
```

the `finally` block is guaranteed to be executed after the `try` block no matter what happens in the `try` block. Even if no exception was raised.

`finally` is generally used to release resources, clean up of variables etc.